# Conditional Efficiency

Tags: java

Below I have a method in which given an array of integers called num, the method returns true if 1, 2, 3 are in the array, in consecutive order. There is no problem with this program. However, the conditionals in the for loop seem a bit repetitive and tedious. Is there an easier, more efficient way to get around this? (i.e. some kind of loop?)

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
    boolean first = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <nums.length-2; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] == 1)
        {
            if (nums[i+1] == 2)
            {
                if (nums[i+2] == 3)
                {
                    first = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

Comment: Why using for loop when you not even going in second iteration.

Comment: @Sneh read the question again..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a codereview of working code. Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm confused, why do you think this is sub-optimal? This problem as defined is by necessity *O(n)* for unstructured data, and you have an *O(n)* solution. You could get a slightly better *O(n)* by skipping ahead by an index or two if the checks for 2 or 3 fail. But everything else is going to be a stylistic thing, which is off topic on SO.

Comment: I don't think he is asking for the optimal solution when it comes to speed, rather how to get rid of the nested `if`-statements..

Comment: @Tobb I think according to question he is saying for loop is repetitive and he wants to keep for loop and get rid of if statements, but I don't see the need of using a for loop.

Comment: @Sneh he is not saying that, he is saying that *the conditionals* in the for loop seem repetetive.

Comment: @Tobb Yeah sorry he is saying conditionals in for loop are repetitive but what I am saying is why is he even using a for loop for this.?

Comment: @Tobb Sure, but at the end of the day it's all going to perform the same as the code they've written (or worse). So they're asking for purely stylistic advice, which belongs on CodeReview.

Comment: @Sneh Because the input array is of unknown size, and they want to find if the three-element sequence `[1,2,3]` appears somewhere in it?

Comment: @Sneh the for loop is obviously needed since we can't know the size of the array he is checking.

Comment: @aruisdante I agree, close vote from me as well..

Comment: @Tobb thanks for pointing that out. Not sure how I missed it -_-

Comment: Also this program will throw errors if the array is of size less than 3.

Comment: @Sneh I decided to omit that since it was not related to the question I was asking

Comment: @awathieu all right.

Comment: I was looking more at some kind of for loop inside. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify it like this:

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i <nums.length-2; i++){
        if(nums[i] == 1 && nums[i + 1] == 2 && nums[i + 2] == 3) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can't come up with any other way to simplify it.. +1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably do what you want it to. In this particular case because you aren't doing anything complicated you can ditch the results variable and just directly return the answer you want. Mostly a matter of preference.

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
    int check = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] == check || nums[i] == 1) 
        {
          if(check == 3)
          {
              return true;
          }
          check = nums[i]+1;
        } 
        else {
          check = 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT
A cleaner solution would actually be something like this

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
    int check = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] == check) {
            if(check == 3) {
                return true;
            }
            check++;
        } else if(check > 1) {
            check = 1;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: or, for a more general solution... store the numbers [1,2,3] in their own array and use "check" as the index (init to 0 and look for check==2)

Comment: @Paul David This code, however does not work if the nums array is {1, 1, 2, 3, 1}. It will evaluate to false, even though it should evaluate to true.

Comment: @AWATHIEU hmm, true. Well, then, it starts to get ugly again if you want to fix that. You could add `|| nums[i] == 1` to the if condition and then replace `check++` with `check = nums[i]+1` or something like that.